# Check if stored proc exists in DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

i am trying to grant execute privs in stored proc in more than one database. The problem is this stored proc might not be in some of the databases. So how can i write a script which checks if stored proc exists in database and if does then provide execute privs for user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[your_procedure_name]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
BEGIN
  -- Set privileges here
END
```

Answer (score 5):

many ways to do it:

1)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
       FROM   sysobjects 
       WHERE  name = N'proc1' 
       AND    type = 'P')
```

2)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   information_schema.routines
           WHERE  routine_name = 'Proc1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if exists (select 1
      from sysobjects
      where  id = object_id('YourProc')
      and type = 'P')
```